# Window 10 not appearing on GRUB after fresh Arch install

Tags: arch-linux, windows, grub

I have a computer with two SSDs, one with Windows 10 and another with Arch, freshly installed.

When I boot up and get to the Grub menu, the only options available are for Arch and Advanced Setup for Arch. No Windows 10.

When I select Arch, log in as `root`, and run `fdisk -l`, here's the output.

[image]

Comment: run `update-grub`

Comment: Also with mounting the EFI and Windows system partition and running `os-prober`. More here https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dual_boot_with_Windows#UEFI_systems

Comment: @jsotola I ran ‘sudo update-grub’ but got “command not found” as output.

Comment: @Biswapriyo I installed ‘os-prober’ and ran ‘os-prober’ but got no output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try mounting the Windows partition and running `sudo grub-mkconfig -o <path-to-grub.cfg>` now that you have os-prober installed. On my system the path is /boot/grub/grub.cfg.

Comment: What code should I run to mount the Windows partition?

Comment: @Username I would try `sudo mount <device> /mnt`, where `<device>` is the partition. If the Samsung 860 in the screenshot is the SSD with Windows, for example, the device would be /dev/sdd1.